# About the continuity of a function on BV

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

For a fixed $u \in BV(\mathbb{R}^N)$, consider the function 
$h:(0,+\infty) \to BV(\mathbb{R}^N)$, given by

$h(t) = u (tx)$.

Is $h$ continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the strong topology: for instance take $u:=1_{(-1,1)}$, i.e. the characteristic function of the interval $(-1,1)$ on $\mathbb R$ (in this example $N=1$). Then $\|h(t)-h(s)\|_{BV}\ge 2$ whenever $s\neq t$, since the distributional derivative of the element $h(s)\in BV(\mathbb R)$ is $\delta_{-1/s}-\delta_{1/s}$.

**However**, continuity holds in an intermediate topology, namely the one given by the distance
$$d(u,v):=\|u-v\|_{L^1}+\big|\|Du\|(\mathbb R^N)-\|Dv\|(\mathbb R^N)\big|,$$
which is good enough for many applications. The proof of continuity can be done by approximating your function $u$ with smooth, compactly supported functions (which can be done in this topology but not in the strong one).

Comment: That's right! Thank you for your clear explanation. In fact I did know that this function is continuous in the intermediate topology, since
$\|h(t)\|_{BV} = t^{N-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|Du| + t^N \|u\|_{L^1}$.
However, I'm not sure if this "weak" continuity would be enough for my purposes.
Thank you anyway.